# Filling a 2d character array from a file in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

I'm a beginner in java and I am trying to fill a 2d character array from an input file. To do this I constructed a method which takes in a 2d character array as a parameter variable, then reads the file and stores it as a character array. So far I have done everything except fill the array, as when I run the code the program throws a NoSuchElement exception. If anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

```
public static char [][] MakeWordArray (char [][] givenArray)
    {
    try
       {
        File wordFile= new File ("words.txt");
        Scanner in= new Scanner (wordFile);
        int rows =0;
        int col=0;
        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
            rows = rows + 1;
            col = col + 1;
            in.next();       
        }
        char [][] words = new char [rows][col];
        File wordFile2= new File ("words.txt");
        Scanner in2= new Scanner(wordFile2);
        for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
          {
              String wordly = in2.nextLine();
              words [i][j] = wordly.charAt(i);
          }
        }
        return words;
       }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
         System.out.println("File Does Not Exist");
        }
    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your counting methods have some problems.
If you want to count how many lines your .txt have:

```
int counter = 0;

         while (in.hasNextLine())
         {
            counter++;
            in.nextLine();
         }
```

If you want to count how many `char` your .txt have:

```
int counterWithoutSpace = 0, counterWithSpace = 0;

         while (in.hasNextLine())
         {
            String line = in.nextLine();

            Scanner inLine = new Scanner(line);
            while (inLine.hasNext())
            {
               String nextWord = inLine.next();
               counterWithoutSpace += nextWord.length();
               counterWithSpace += nextWord.length() + 1;
            }
            counterWithSpace--;
         }
```

If you want to count how many char you have on each line, I recommend [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Because the size of your array is dynamic. 
Note that you can also you can use the char counter logic above with [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) too.
See as follows:

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

         while (in.hasNextLine())
         {
            arr.add(in.nextLine().length());
         }
```

And if you realy needs the static array, you can use:

```
Integer[] intArr = arr.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

You can transform its entire function as below to get a list of every `Character` of the .txt:

```
List<Character> arr = new ArrayList<Character>();

         while (in.hasNextLine())
         {
            String line = in.nextLine();

            for (char c : line.toCharArray())
            {
               arr.add(c);
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a do while loop instead of the while

```
do
{
rows=rows+1;
col=lol+1;
in.next();
}
while(in.hasNext());
```

Comment: Do u have to use in.hasNextLine? Try using in.hasNext

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple questions here.

1) Why did you provide a char[][] parameter when you are not even using it?

2) Why are you using two files when all you need to do is read from a file and convert it in 2d Array?

3) The method name should follow camel casing convention.

From what i understood from your question, This is a code i've tried.

**NOTE- because the requirement is of an `Array` and not dynamic datatypes like `List ArrayList` etc., the data entered into char array might be lost**

Saying that here is what works.

```
  public class StackOverflow{
    public static char [][] makeWordArray ()
    {
        try{
            File f  = new File("C:\\docs\\mytextfile.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
            int row = 0, col = 0;
            String readData = "";
            while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                readData += scan.nextLine(); 
                row++;  
            }
            double range = (readData.length()/row); 
            col = (int)Math.ceil(range);
            char[][] arr = new char[row][col];
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
                    arr[i][j] = readData.charAt(count++); 
                    System.out.println("Pos: ["+ i +"][" + j + "]" + arr[i][j]);
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fe){
            System.err.println(fe.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        char[][] myarr = StackOverflow.makeWordArray();
        //print your array
    }
 }
```